# Override admin file for module

Tags: prestashop

i would to override the file below in my module
 /data/www/clients/client1/web1/web/adminXXX/themes/default/js/bundle/product/product-related.js  file .

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

JS core files cannot be overridden, you'll have to add your own JS file like described here, https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/

Hopefully it won't clash with the core one's functions and variables.